# GWT CSS Styling Framework

Tags: css, gwt

Is there a sort of css framework which i can add to a gwt project, and this will completely set a new UI to my gwt application. Sort of changing the look and feel.

I love GWT, but others like Vaadin are so good styled, if there were a complete set of css librarys that would make my app a lot nicer would we great.

I think we can be great developers but not so good designers.

Thanks!

Comment: How about [gwt-bootstrap](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend starting with http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/

As well as: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss

I would then dive deeper into the GWT docs to get a good handle on creating your custom themes. At some point any styling theme/framework will fail your needs and you will need to have some fundamentals for styling yourself.

Personally, I highly recommend using UiBinder and ClientBundle:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder

http://granitode.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/gwt-uibinder-using-a-clientbundle-with-cssresources/

Comment: Im using UI Binder, is there a way to use bottstrap without UI BInder?, if not, do you recommend star using ui Binder?

Comment: You can view the installation (vai Gwt module.gwt.xml) and an example of how to use this WITH UiBinder. I have not used GwtBootstrap, but I believe you can use it with our without UiBinder. But I recommend UiBinder (most of the time) http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/gwt-bootstrap/apidocs/

Answer (score 0):

@fguespe, I'm not aware of something such for example twitter bootstrap that you 'just' plug.

Eventually the 'web designer' needs to know about specific gwt CSS classes that impact the look and feel. If importing the GWT 'non plain' themes, you'll need to write customizations.

Yes indeed Vaadin and GXT provide a default nicer look and feel... Let's just fire all Google devs for a lack of focus :-)